# Custom function with pandas assign to get the match in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, assign, method-chaining

Imagine I have a table with one column, product_line. I want to create another column with the product_line_name, based on the product_line number. The information is taken from a dictionary.
I have declared a dictionary containing product lines and descriptions:

```
categories={
'Apparel': 99,
'Bikes': 32}


########   function that returns the category from a gl number
def get_cat(glnum,dic=categories):
    for cat, List in dic.items():
        if glnum in List:
            return cat
    return(0)

data['category']=data['product_line'].apply(lambda x: get_cat(x))
```

Works

However I cannot get it to work using method chaining:

```
tt = (tt
      .assign(category = lambda d: get_cat(d.gl_product_line)))
```

It should be an error related to the Series but I am unsure why it wouldn't work since the lambda function should call the get_cat repeatedly for each row of the dataframe - which does not happen apparently.

Any ideas of how I could do this using the .assign in method chaining?

Comment: `dic=categories` but `for cat, List in dic.items()` indicates that `cat` should be a string like 'Apparel' and `List` should be an integer like 99. I am curious as to why you have `glnum` in `List` when `List` is an integer. Or perhaps I am reading this wrong

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy it's because the column I am trying to transform has number representing the product line, and I want to get the category in as a String. Not sure if that answered your question